# Fixed positioning of divs between two points of scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have seven boxes. First I want to scroll box1 normally. When box2 reaches the top of the viewport it should be fixed same as in the example. I have to animate (animations may be show/hide etc) some views when I scroll on box2 again and again (Maybe for two window height or X pixel height). After the completion of animations, I need to remove the fixed positioning and start scrolling the remaining boxes normally. Any help?

[ I may use the same fixed positioning for box4 or box5 again while scrolling ]

[Example http://jsfiddle.net/z0yv9gox/](http://jsfiddle.net/z0yv9gox/)

Here is by code

```js
var winHit = $(window).height();
var winWid = $(window).width();
$('.box').css({'height':winHit+'px','width':winWid+'px'});

$(window).scroll(function(){
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > winHit) {
      $('.box2').addClass('fixed');
   }
  else{
    $('.box2').removeClass('fixed');
  }
  });
```

```css
.box{height:200px;}
.box1{background:#333}
.box2{background:#ccffff;}
.box3{background:#999}
.box4{background:#ffcccc}
.box5{background:#666}
.box6{background:#999}
.box7{background:#333}

.fixed{position:fixed; top:0; left:0; z-index:2; width:100%;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="box box1"></div>
<div class="box box2"></div>
<div class="box box3"></div>
<div class="box box4"></div>
<div class="box box5"></div>
<div class="box box6"></div>
<div class="box box7"></div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$(window).scroll( function() { $(this).scrollTop() > winHit });`

Answer (score 0):

So if I am understanding you correctly I think you will want to put the box you want to fix inside of another div and relatively position that div and give it the height of how far you want your fixed box to travel (In my example I give it 300vh in css but if you want to add this height by javascript like in your above example you can).  Then you will want to fix your box once the window gets to the top of your relatively positioned parent box.  That way when you travel the required distance you can add another class the gives your fixed box an absolute position again this time placed on the bottom of your relatively positioned parent box.  You will need 2 if statements for this and also you will need to calculate the height of your parent box and your fixed box.  Then once the top of the window hits the top of your fixed box holder you add the fixed class and when the scroll position hits the fixed box holders height minus your fixed box's height you can add another class sticking it to the bottom of that div.  If I am misunderstanding your question please let me know in the comments below.

Ok so I know that may have been kind of confusing so here it is in action along with a fiddle I worked up.

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/yovtma0y/)

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
  var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  $('.fixed-box-holder').each(function(){
    var boxTop = $(this).offset().top;
    var boxHolderHeight = $(this).height();
    var fixedBox = $(this).children('.fixed-box');
    var boxHeight = fixedBox.height();
    var boxStop = boxHolderHeight - boxHeight;
    
    if (windowTop >=  boxTop) {
      fixedBox.addClass('fixed');
    }else{
      fixedBox.removeClass('fixed');
    }
    if(windowTop >= boxTop + boxStop){
      fixedBox.addClass('scrolled');
    }else{
      fixedBox.removeClass('scrolled');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body{margin:0;}
.box{
  height:100vh;
  color:#fff;
}
.fixed-box-holder{
  position:relative;
  height:300vh;
}
.fixed-box{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  background:blue;
}
.fixed{
  position:fixed; 
  z-index:1; 
}
.scrolled{
  position:absolute;
  top:auto;
  bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box" style="background:#333;">First Box</div>
<div class="fixed-box-holder">
  <div class="box fixed-box">Fixed Box</div>
</div>
<div class="box" style="background:#444;">Second Box</div>
<div class="box" style="background:#555;">Third Box</div>
<div class="box" style="background:#666;">Fourth Box</div>
<div class="fixed-box-holder">
  <div class="box fixed-box">Fixed Box</div>
</div>
<div class="box" style="background:#777;">Fifth Box</div>
<div class="box" style="background:#888;">Sixth Box</div>
<div class="box" style="background:#999;">Seventh Box</div>
```

PS on slower machines you may have some issues with smoothness as this will be a lot of calculations on the fly especially if you are going to be adding animations as well so just keep that in mind.